# Create 1000 samples of 30 observations from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I have got a data.frame and I need to create 1000 random samples, each one containing 30 observations.

Here an example of my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID Letter
1 L
2 R
3 T
4 U
5 I
6 K
7 Y
8 Q
9 A 
10 R', header = TRUE)
```

The column from where the samples must be taken is `df$Letter`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use `sample` along with `replicate` to create 100 samples of length 30 with replacement, e.g., `replicate(100,sample(df$Letter, 30, replace =TRUE))`. You do not need the `boot` package.

Comment: Bootstrap resamples are the same size as the original sample. Since you want to have resamples larger than the original sample, you are not doing bootstrap and thus can't use the `boot` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sample` along with `replicate` to create 100 samples of length 30 with replacement. You do not need the boot package. Following your answer, you can just use `simplify = FALSE` to prevent coercing into an array.

```
replicate(100,sample(df$Letter, 30, replace =TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
```

The result will be a list.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @shayaa, here the solution of my question:

```
samples = replicate(1000,sample(df$Letter, 30, replace =TRUE)) #a matrix has been created
```

for convenience I converted the matrix into a list:

```
samples_list = split(samples, rep(1:ncol(samples), each = nrow(samples)))
```